# Demand classification

Tags: forecasting, forecastability

Most of the industries use a following approach to classify the demand pattern.
Smooth demand (ADI < 1.32 and CV² < 0.49).

Intermittent demand (ADI >= 1.32 and CV² < 0.49).

Erratic demand (ADI < 1.32 and CV² >= 0.49).

Lumpy demand (ADI >= 1.32 and CV² >= 0.49).

My question is, is there a proper literature or resource materials on why the threshold values are set to 1.32 and 0.49 for ADI and CV2 for classifying the demand as smooth, Intermittent, lumpy and erratic.

Please advise.

Thank you

Comment: See https://robjhyndman.com/publications/a-note-on-the-categorization-of-demand-patterns/

Comment: Thank you Rob. Also these threshold values 0.49 and 1.32 are specific to a particular industry?

Comment: Read the paper. It is a mathematical argument. Nothing to do with the origin of the data.